# White space on top and bottom Python matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to plot a tabular chart in Python and save this table as a jpeg/png. Then using this image in the mail. The problem is I am getting white space on top and bottom of the chart. Code I used to achieve this:

```
nrows, ncols = len(df)+1, len(df.columns)
hcell, wcell = 0.5, 1.5
hpad, wpad = 0, 0  
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(ncols*wcell+wpad, nrows*hcell+hpad))

ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')
fig.savefig('table1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Output:
[image: tabular table]
Also, I want to give the heading to the top and left-side of the chart.
'Some text Here' is the heading and yellow line shows where I want another heading.
Desired Output without extra white space on the top.
[image: Desired]

Comment: You might want to give us a working example so we could reproduce your case, and work on it.

Comment: I gave the code. Data one can reproduce.

Comment: The answer has been given wtf

Comment: @AyushKesarwani "Data one can reproduce" is not how it works here. You provide a [mcve], someone can give an answer. If you don't provide such [mcve], you are basically asking for the one who wants to answer to not only solve your problem, but also first write that [mcve] himself. This is not very nice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will make sure I follow this from next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to specify the bounding box of the table as the one to be used when saving the figure.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colums = ['col1', 'col2']
rows = ['row1', 'row2']
values = [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
table = ax.table(cellText=values, colLabels=colums, rowLabels=rows, loc='center')

ax.axis('off')

fig.canvas.draw()
bbox = table.get_window_extent(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
bbox_inches = bbox.transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())

fig.savefig('plop.png', bbox_inches=bbox_inches)

plt.show()
```

[image]

In this case the outer lines are croped because the line extends to both sides of its position. One may still add a little bit of padding around the table. E.g. to have 5 pixels padding,

```
bbox = table.get_window_extent(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
bbox = bbox.from_extents(bbox.xmin-5, bbox.ymin-5, bbox.xmax+5, bbox.ymax+5)
bbox_inches = bbox.transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can delete the white spaces above and below your table. [Reading the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig), you already have the **tighest** you will ever achieve.

> bbox_inches : str or Bbox, optional
>
> Bbox in inches. Only the given portion of the figure is saved. If ‘tight’, try to figure out the tight bbox of the figure. If None, use savefig.bbox

However, I have made a working example for your properly set rows and columns.
Here is the code, following the image.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

colums = ['col1', 'col2']
rows = ['row1', 'row2']
values = [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
ax.table(cellText=values, colLabels=colums, rowLabels=rows, loc='center')

ax.axis('off')
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

fig.savefig('plop.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: Result]

I strongly advise you to adjust your *axis / figure* settings **after** your plot is entirely drawn.

Comment: Of course you can get rid of the white spaces, but `bbox_inches='tight'` would not help too much for that purpose. As soon as the question shows a [mcve], I'm happy to provide an answer shown how.

Comment: I am eager to know how you would do. The only way I could find to achieve this is to use a [Bbox](https://matplotlib.org/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox) instance, but I don't have time to encapsulate its power right now. I'd be glad if you'd be nice enough to send me a direct message with the options I should look into.

Comment: Ok, I took your example and used it for an answer using `bbox_inches`. There are of course also other options, like making the table exactly as large as the figure.